# Can I make python ignore certain excepts from a different file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have an ElementClickInterceptedException except in a function in a file. Which is relevant in the majority of other functions I import it to:

```
class SeleniumExtended:

 def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver=driver
    self.default_timeout=15
    self.actions = ActionChains(self.driver)

 def wait_and_click(self, locator, timeout=None):
    timeout = timeout if timeout else self.default_timeout
    print(locator)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        raise Exception(f"Element: {locator} not displayed with after timeout of {timeout} ")
    **except ElementClickInterceptedException:**
        element = self.driver.find_element(*locator)
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

I imported this class and function to a different file, in which I have another function that also excepts ElementClickInterceptedException.

```
   class logs(LOGS_LOCATORS):

     def __init__(self, driver):
       self.driver = driver
       self.sl = SeleniumExtended(self.driver)
     
     def click_on_settings_btn(self):
      try:
        self.sl.wait_and_click(self.locator, timeout=100)
   ****except ElementClickInterceptedException:

        self.sl.wait_until_element_disappears(self.locator2)
        self.sl.wait_and_click(self.locator3)
```

I want this specific function to ignore the imported wait_and_click except ElementClickInterceptedException. So it does execute the code for the exception in the click_on_settings_btn function, But ignore the code in the imported wait_and_click function. Is this possible?

Comment: I didn't know WebDriverWait could throw anything but TimeoutException. I'm more familiar with the C# API, though.